# How to use array_map with a function that takes more than one parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, array-map

I have an array that contains string that have **underscores** or **_** in them, I need to replace the underscores with spaces using str_replace and I want to do it using **array_map()**

**array_map** can take function that only have one parameter in them but **str_replace** takes three parameters:

1. What to replace
2. Replace it with what
3. String

I can perfectly use a foreach loop to do the following but I was wondering how would I be able to do it with **array_map**. I did some looking on google and in stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution.

Here's an example of the array that I have

```
$array = array("12_3","a_bc");
```

Comment: Well the title of that is not really clear to how it involves my problem, just the body. You can't expect me to find it with such a title really..

Comment: If you search for 'array_map' you get plenty of examples imho!

Comment: My bad. will search more generally next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
<?php
function replace($array)
{
    $replace_res = str_replace('_', ' ', $array);
    return  $replace_res;
}

$array = array("12_3","a_bc");
$result = array_map("replace", $array);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem would be to make a wrapper function that returns a string in the format you want using str_replace and then map that to the array.

Although if you read the documentation it says: "The number of parameters that the callback function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to the array_map()"

The third argument is: "Variable list of array arguments to run through the callback function."

So you would want to do array_map("function", array_you_want_changed, array_of_paramters);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

See example 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can solve your problem.

```
$array = array("12_3","a_bc");

$find = array_fill(0, count($array), '_');
$replace = array_fill(0, count($array), ' ');


$out = array_map('str_replace', $find, $replace ,$array);

print_r($out);
```